# podman "The cgroupv2 manager is set to systemd but there is no systemd user session available" warning

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, podman

### Context

I am using a Raspberry Pi running on Raspbian. I connect remotely using `ssh`.
I want to use `podman` for building images and running containers, the exact same way I've done on my local machine.
The installation of `podman` has been done the exact same way.

### Issue

Every time the `podman` command is used on the RPi, I get the following warning:

```
WARN[0000] The cgroupv2 manager is set to systemd but there is no systemd user session available 
WARN[0000] For using systemd, you may need to login using an user session 
WARN[0000] Alternatively, you can enable lingering with: `loginctl enable-linger 1000` (possibly as root) 
WARN[0000] Falling back to --cgroup-manager=cgroupfs    
WARN[0000] The cgroupv2 manager is set to systemd but there is no systemd user session available 
WARN[0000] For using systemd, you may need to login using an user session 
WARN[0000] Alternatively, you can enable lingering with: `loginctl enable-linger 1000` (possibly as root) 
WARN[0000] Falling back to --cgroup-manager=cgroupfs
```

### What I found

I've found [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/12983) which seems to be focusing on this warning, but I cannot understand what the underlying issue might be, and the solution they give (installing the `dbus-user-session` package) doesn't seem to work, as it already is installed on my RPi.

### What I need

I'm not sure where this warning comes from and, although I cannot be sure of it, I suspect there might be some effects I have yet to see on the way the images are build/run/etc.
I think it may be related to the users permission, but have no idea how to verify this.

Do any of you have an explanation?

Answer (score 2):

Try what `podman` suggests in the 3rd line (enabling lingering), which helped me on a related system with common ancestor (Ubuntu 22.04):

```
$ loginctl enable-linger $USER
```

---

You can test if it worked by e.g.:

`$ loginctl show-user "$USER" --property=Linger | grep -q 'yes'`

- a failure message would be:

`Failed to get user: User ID 1000 is not logged in or lingering`